# libcurl mismatch in curl and curl-config

Tags: python, linux, curl, libcurl, centos6

i am quite new to curl development. I am working on centOS and i want to install pycurl 7.19.5, but i am unable to as i need libcurl 7.21.2 or above.I tried installing an updated curl but it is still pointing to the old libcurl.
curl-config --version
libcurl 7.24.0
curl --version 
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.7.3 libidn/1.29 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp  Features: AsynchDNS Debug TrackMemory IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz.
Can anyone please help me how i can update the libcurl version in curl

Comment: For future people experiencing this problem: after `sudo reboot` my curl version matched up with my libcurl version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two versions installed, curl-config --version shows the newer version (7.24.0) and curl (the tool) is the newer version but when it runs the run-time linker ld.so finds and uses the older version (7.21.1).

Check /etc/ld.so.conf for which dirs that are check in which order and see if you can remove one of the versions or change order of the search.

Answer (score 1):

For further information, find all installed libcurl using command:

```
$ find /usr -name "libcurl*"
```

I'm sure libcurl file with latest edit date & time is file what you want.

To resolve the problem the safest way is creating new soft link to it. But before doing that, finding out how libraries loaded by order is necessary, issue this command to find out how libraries and its folder loaded by order (first line mean first loaded):

```
$ libconfig -v | less
```

Then create new soft link inside folder that relatively load first before unwanted libcurl's folder.